# ¿Abrir una ventana nueva automáticamente?

Tags: javascript

Buen día hay alguna manera de que se ejecute esta ventana sin utilizar algún onClick,entrare a un link y en esa ventana después de unos segundos abrirá esta:

```
function Ventana()

    {
        var URL= "informacion/fechas.jsp";
            ventana=window.open(URL, "self", "status=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,resizable=yes,width=850,height=500");
             $('#gif_espera').html("&nbsp;");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si tienes jquey puedes hacer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Ventana();
});
```

Esto se ejecuta cuando todo el contenido HTML está listo.

Y si no vas a usar la funcion Ventana de nuevo, puede hacer directamente:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var URL= "informacion/fechas.jsp";
    ventana=window.open(URL, "self", "status=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,resizable=yes,width=850,height=500");
    $('#gif_espera').html("&nbsp;");
});
```

Tambien puedes usar window.onload() si no tiene jquery:

```
function Ventana()
{
    var URL= "informacion/fechas.jsp";
    ventana=window.open(URL, "self", "status=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,resizable=yes,width=850,height=500");
    $('#gif_espera').html("&nbsp;");
}

window.onload() = Ventana;
```

Answer (score 3):

Para que un evento se ejecute despues de cierto tiempo puedes utilizar [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), y si quieres que algo se ejecute automáticamente puedes utilizar `(function() { // Función })();`, combinando ambas tenemos

```js
(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Me ejecuté 1 segundo después de invocada la función :)');
  }, 1000);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrias utilizar la funcion `window.setTimeout(código, tiempo_retraso)`, donde el codigo puede ser una llamada a tu funcion `Ventana` y tiempo_retraso es el tiempo que le das(en milisegundos) para su llamada.

**Ejemplo:**

```
function Ventana()
{
    var URL= "informacion/fechas.jsp";
    ventana=window.open(URL, "self", "status=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,resizable=yes,width=850,height=500");
    $('#gif_espera').html("&nbsp;");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    window.setTimeout(Ventana,5000)//5 segundos de espera.
});
```